# How to read a local file by chunks in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, file-io, universalxpconnect

I learned how to read a local file by chunks with the help of JavaScript in Firefox ( [How to read a local file by chunks in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638887/how-to-read-a-local-file-by-chunks-in-javascript) ).

But I wonder what if I want to read a certain range of bytes, not first several, but, say, `100-200`? Is it possible to set the offsets somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Use `nsISeekableStream` instead. It allows you to `seek()` in a file.